# How do I get the agora video SDK for unity video working on my builds?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, agora.io

I downloaded the Agora Video SDK for Unity and it came with two demo scenes titled SceneHome and SceneHelloVideo. I assured that the App ID field of my Test Home component that was attatched to the GameController object contained my App ID. I followed the android instructions in the read me files. When I build my project for android and join a channel via my Samsung device, the video does not work unless I tab out the app and reenter. Also, when 2 unique Samsung devices join the channel, we cannot see or hear each other (as if we joined 2 separate channels). I also followed the Windows tutorial version here: https://medium.com/@jake_agora.io/windows-run-video-chat-within-your-unity-application-f400f9056749 and the camera only works on my PC if I plug my USB camera in and out. Why may these circumstances be occurring? Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you have to give us a minimal reproducible example to be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Well thing the thing is there is no specific portion of the code that is failing. I literally downloaded the agora video SDK for unity, plugged in my app id and it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

just wondering if you received my message on Youtube. It is good to see you here. I am wondering if you ever received a Android permission popup asking for the camera permission? If you didn't grant the permission you won't see the video at all.  It may be the same story on Windows.  Did you run that test again with the camera attached before starting up Unity? Also, when you sign up at Agora, did you create the project with Certificate enabled? If yes, then you may got a token credential issue.  We can talk about that if there is no permission issue.

Comment: It seems there is no more follow up after chatting in Slack.  Anthony could just have an user error.

Comment: Others if you have similar issue, please check the FAQ (https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq?platform=All%20Platforms).  and  come to the Slack channel and search for previous posts.  A lots of non-displaying issues are mostly because of using AppId incorrectly or having camera permission issues.